# Can I reuse FBOs between QQuickFramebufferObjects?

Tags: opengl, optimization, qml, qtquick2, fbo

I very often allocate QQuickFramebufferObjects (QQFBOs) and then quickly deallocate them. This takes up CPU. One way I've devised to decrease CPU usage is to preserve already-allocated FBOs after the destruction of their owning QQFBOs, and provide them (as rendertargets) to any new QQFBOs that I allocate after that. That way I'd save the FBO allocation/deallocation overhead. The problem is when a QQFBO is destroyed, it destroys its owned FBO as well. **Is there a way to achieve what I want anyway?**

Notes:

- All my FBOs do have the same size and format.
- My optimization idea is not supported by profiling data, because my profiler gives me rather nonsensical results in this case.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just keep those objects around? Why do you *need* to deallocate them?

Comment: @NicolBolas: You mean the QQFBOs? I need to deallocate them for 2 reasons: to save memory (I replace them with cheap impostors when they don't need to animate) and to save CPU usage on repainting (QtQuick penalizes you for having a lot of complex allocated items).

Comment: @NicolBolas: I could reuse the entire QQFBOs (as in, a pool of QQFBOs) instead of deallocating, but that would be a bit more involved.

Comment: "*that would be a bit more involved*" How? What you want is to have a pool of FBOs. Either way, you have to have the logic for a pool of objects; the only question is what objects go into that pool.

Comment: @NicolBolas: FBOs are "context-free" objects - you can take one from context A, transplant it into context B and after you glClear it, it'll keep functioning just fine. FBOs can even exist "outside a context", in a pool. My QQFBO subclass's instances, however, are "living objects". They can't exist outside their intended context. E.g. my QQFBO subclass exposes a `mouseArea` property that must be assigned from outside, and connects to its signals. You can see that in a pool, no such mouseArea will exist, so the sig connections will fail. So will bindings, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "context free" objects. FBOs are OpenGL container objects; they *cannot* be shared between contexts. Unless you're using a different definition of "context" here. Equally importantly, what is going on with a *framebuffer* such that it needs "a `mouseArea` property"? If that's the kind of nonsense API that Qt supports, maybe you should just stop using it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149034/discussion-between-stefan-monov-and-nicol-bolas).